# How do we decide which tools to use to test web and mobile applications?

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, web-application, mobile-automation, web-testing

My friend and I have just started our business that aims to conduct web and mobile application testing. We have read a lot and learned how to perform such testing. However, throughout our reading, we found out that many testing tools have been suggested to consider which makes it very difficult to decide how to choose the best tool and which tool is considered better to be used.

Based on your experience, can you please suggest any thoughts of how to decide which of the web and mobile testing tools we go with? I will be thankful if you suggest some tools' names.

Comment: Voting for Closing. Questions of type "how to test?", without a specific context, are usually not in the scope of the site. I would suggest adding to your question what is the exact context of your testing mission, what you are trying to investigate, what have you tried so far, and what you are missing.

Answer (score 3):

**It depends**

The long version:

The tools you choose will depend on the nature of the software you are testing and your clients' needs.

Some of the factors you should take into consideration are:

**Budget** - If your budget is constrained, you will probably want to work primarily with free tooling. This is possible, but will typically be more time-consuming than working with paid tools (although that is not necessarily the case).

**Platform** - The application platform will impose its own requirements. Tools that are Windows-centric often do not work well on Mac or Linux platforms, and vice versa. There is also a large divide between desktop platforms, web platforms, and mobile platforms.

**Client Requirements** - Your clients will have requirements. These can impose limitations on your tool choices: if your clients require PDF reports of test outcomes, you will need to find a way to provide that.

**Reporting Requirements** - You will need to keep track of what you have tested for which client, and your time (and money) investment in their work. You may find an all-in-one tool that will allow you to manage your testing and reporting in an integrated fashion, or you may need to build something. Either way, this will impact your tooling choice, since you will definitely want to make this process as automated as possible.

**Your Team Skills** - If your test team (which will likely be you and your friend to start with, but will grow if all goes well) have little experience with scripted/coded test automation your tool choices will be limited. Similarly, if your team is largely accustomed to working with Java, they may find difficulty if the tooling does not support Java or JavaScript (JavaScript may still cause difficulties because it is so similar to Java in appearance but so much more flexible).

**Summary** - I'd recommend you look at all these factors and aim for the most flexible set of tooling you can use as a starting point. If all goes well for your new business you can always add other tools as needed.

Answer (score 0):

As application testing is really an important aspect and moreover it can be cumbersome sometimes with change in technogies and OS versions to purchase devices every now and than. So as top software testing companies, the inventory should be there however cloud based paid testing tools such as Browser Stackor Device Farms can be used to leverage testing on Web and Mobile devices.